# Laravel 4 - Inserting multiple values into a pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, pivot-table

I have a users table and also an accounts table.

This accounts table defines which accounts a user can have.

e.g.

accounts:

```
id| name

1 | library
2 | school
3 | maths
```

users:

```
id| username

1 | username1
2 | username2
```

I now have another table: users_accounts

```
user_id | account_id
```

I am making an interface for new users to be created. On this page I have basic details but also a list of checkboxes (created from the accounts table). The checkboxes represent what account a user needs to have set up for them.

What I want to do is when creating the account:

```
$user = User::create($input);
```

I want to also add the user id and the accounts they need setting up into the users_accounts table. A single user can have multiple accounts required.

Can I do this using a pivot table and belongsToMany?

In long terms:

```
$user = User::create($input);

loop through the checkboxes {
    add a new row into the user_accounts table with the ticked checkboxes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there!

```
$user = User::create($input);

$userAccounts = array();
foreach ($checkboxes as $accountId) {
    $userAccounts[] = new UserAccount(['account_id' => $accountId]);
}
$user->accounts()->saveMany($userAccounts);
```

Doc:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models